# Can I test deadlock in googletest?

Tags: c++, deadlock, googletest

I have a small class that creates multiple threads. When I call `stop()` method, it sets a flag for stopping threads and joins on the thread until they are stopped. Here is the code of `stop()` method:

```
void stop() {
    running_flag_ = false;
    for (auto& th : threads_) {
        if (th.joinable())
            th.join();
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to test if this method works as expected, meaning this method should always return. I don't think dead test is really suitable here. Any idea if there is a way to test this?

Comment: Note that if you write a timeout test and it fails, then you have a bug. If your timeout test passes, there's no guarantee that there's no bug. Is `running_flag_` synchronized between threads? Perhaps a `std::atomic<bool>`?

Comment: @JohnFilleau There is no problem currently with my code. But I just want to write a test to check code functionality correctly. is There timeout for running each test? can I adjust it?

Comment: I get that. You're writing a regression test then so that you can prove correctness in the future. I'm saying that testing for a timeout can't prove the absence of deadlocks. It can only prove their presence.

Comment: @JohnFilleau yea, you are correct. timeout test is somehow not safe.

Comment: I think to test against deadlock you would need to identify all resource accesses in each thread, and then permute all possible orderings. If your exotic testing framework can identify all of those accesses though, then it can permute the orderings offline and find any deadlock cases without even running your code.

Comment: that doesn't mean you shouldn't perform a timeout test. It's a great first naive solution -- and in the absence of a formal proof of thread safety, it will catch more bugs than no test at all.

Comment: @JohnFilleau in reality, the code that stops thread should always work correctly **if code used correctly**. But I thought if there was a check to see if a function returns, it can help to test this to some extend. But anyway, if a deadlock happens here, the bug is probably somewhere else. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a deadlock some threads are waiting on locks until they are released. There is no way to recover process form such state, without adding extra code.

The only way to overcome this problem is to detect timeout and crash unit test application when timeout accrues. Some times ago I used this code to detect issue so build machine do not hang to long:

```cpp
class TerminateOnDeadlockGuard final
{
public:
    using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using Duration = Clock::duration;

    explicit TerminateOnDeadlockGuard(Duration timeout = std::chrono::seconds{30});

    ~TerminateOnDeadlockGuard();

private:
    void waitForCompletion();

private:
    const Duration m_timeout;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_wasCompleted;
    std::condition_variable m_guardStarted;
    std::thread m_guardThread;
};
//---------
TerminateOnDeadlockGuard::TerminateOnDeadlockGuard(Duration timeout) : m_timeout{timeout}
{
    m_guardThread = std::thread(&TerminateOnDeadlockGuard::waitForCompletion, this);
    std::unique_lock lock{m_mutex};
    m_guardStarted.wait(lock);
}

TerminateOnDeadlockGuard::~TerminateOnDeadlockGuard()
{
    m_wasCompleted.notify_one();
    m_guardThread.join();
}

void TerminateOnDeadlockGuard::waitForCompletion()
{
    std::unique_lock lock{m_mutex};
    m_guardStarted.notify_one();
    if (std::cv_status::timeout == m_wasCompleted.wait_for(lock, m_timeout))
    {
        std::cerr << "Test timeout!!!" << std::endl;
        std::exit(-1); // you can use `abort` here to create crash log.
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
TEST(SomeTestSuite, myTest)
{
    TerminateOnDeadlockGuard guardDeadLock;

    // test code here
}
```

Now there is [google death test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#death-tests) which could come to the rescue.
This forks process at let child process to terminate.

```cpp
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class NoDeadLockTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    void someTest()
    {
        TerminateOnDeadlockGuard guardDeadLock{5s};
        actualTest();
        std::exit(::testing::Test::HasFailure() ? 2 : 0);
    }

    void actualTest()
    {
#if VERSION == 0
        ASSERT_TRUE(true);
#elif VERSION == 1
        ASSERT_TRUE(false);
#elif VERSION == 2
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
#endif
    }
};

TEST_F(NoDeadLockTest, myTest)
{
    EXPECT_EXIT(someTest(), testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "");
}
```

I've checked this on godbolt and it is far from perfect: https://godbolt.org/z/nasros577 but shows there is hope if some extra effort is done.

I relay recommend to use some tool to detect the dead locks and fix code. I used thread sanitizer - I've tried it and it is very effective.

Comment: Yea, thread sanitizer is great. But I wondered how we can add such test. Thanks for reply. :)

Comment: I never tried, but you can check if google death test could be used for that. It uses `fork` to run test on separate process, so when crash happens main process remains intact. AFAIK google death test are used to test if assertions are triggered on invalid input to the API under test, so most probably no cash scenerio will be reported as failure :(.

Comment: death test check for *processes to die*. So not really sure if they are a good test here.

Comment: You can try and check if death test can do other checks too.

Comment: As you can see I've tried do some test verification on DEATH test and it is silent :( but there is a chance it will work.